# How to create a Static NSMutableArray in a class in Objective c?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, static-members

I have Class A which is super class for both class B and class C. I need to store the objects of Class A in 'static' NSMutablearray defined in Class A. Is it possible to modify data stored in MSMutableArray using methods in Class B and Class C? How to create and initialize Static array? An example would be of more help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
{
}

-(NSMutableArray*) myStaticArray;

@end

@implementation ClassA

-(NSMutableArray*) myStaticArray
{
    static NSMutableArray* theArray = nil;
    if (theArray == nil)
    {
        theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return theArray;
}

@end
```

That is a pattern I use quite a lot instead of true singletons.  Objects of ClassA and its subclasses can use it like this:

```
[[self myStaticArray] addObject: foo];
```

There are variations you can consider e.g. you can make the method a class method.  You might also want to make the method thread safe in a multithreaded environment. e.g.

```
-(NSMutableArray*) myStaticArray
{
    static NSMutableArray* theArray = nil;
    @synchronized([ClassA class])
    {
        if (theArray == nil)
        {
            theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return theArray;
}
```

Comment: won't this cause a memory leak for theArray?

Comment: It'll not leak at all - theArray is defined as static array, thus it'll instantiate this object only once.

Comment: @JeremyP just finding this now. Just wanted to say cheers for this. Great solution!

Comment: @JeremyP actually a follow up question. Where do we dealloc or nil the array when the application closes? It's working for me when my app first launches, but if I close my app my NSMutableArray never gets populated with data. Do you have have to `myArray = [myObject myStaticArray]; myArray = nil;` to get rid of it?

Comment: @skålfyfan The array never gets deallocated because it never gets released.  This is not a problem normally because the address space is about to get zapped anyway.  If you have cleanup stuff you need to do that relies on the objects' deallocate, you need to explicitly run that when the application closes instead.

Comment: @JeremyP the '@synchronized' you added will only make its initialisation thread safe.(Correct me if I am wrong). Read and write operation to this array will not be safe..?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava Correct. You'll need to add other synchronisation to make accessses thread safe.